# Series of derivatives not converging to the derivative of the series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives, examples-counterexamples, uniform-convergence

I want to know if the following is possible:

A sequence $f_n : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ of $C^\infty$ functions such that
$$f := \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$$
converges uniformly to a $C^1$ function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. So far so good but now the crazy stuff begins: I want
$$f'(x) \ne \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n'(x)$$
for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Either by don't letting $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n'(x)$ converge or by being convergent to a different number than $f'(x)$.

**EDIT:** I don't think that my question is simply about interchanging limits. I know that in general this is not allowed. But here we are asking for an example where it doesn't work **for all** (and not only for some) $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: See the second item in the rich site [mathcounterexamples](https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/counterexamples-around-differentiation-of-sequences-of-functions/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interchanging the order of differentiation and summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147869/interchanging-the-order-of-differentiation-and-summation)

Comment: @JeanMarie I guess you mean the example with $f_n(x)=\sin(nx)/\sqrt{n}$. That is a nice one. Of course, to be an example of my question you have to transfer it to a series instead of a sequence, but that's no problem.

Comment: Oh, but it is not clear that sequence of derivaties doesn't converge anywhere. Maybe at some point it converges to $0$ so it is not an example of my question.

Comment: relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3999768/uniform-convergence-of-a-sequence-of-functions-to-a-function-g-but-their-deriv